# R survey package: svyby + svymean: one vs many variables

Tags: r, survey

Let's assume the a data set mydata with the variables foo1..foo20 which are factors with the labels "Easy" and "Difficult". Now let's consider this code:

```
library(survey)
svd <- svydesign(ids = ~ 1, weights = ~ weight, data = mydata)
svyby(~ foo1, by = ~ group, svd, svymean)$foo1Difficult
svyby(~ foo1 + foo2 + foo3 + ... + foo20, by = ~ group, svd, svymean)$foo1Difficult
```

Are the results supposed to be identical? Is there a reason why the results could differ? Why does it make a difference whether I iterate over each variable or use all variables at once?

Comment: could you provide a minimal reproducible example where the results are different?  never seen a circumstance where your syntax would produce different `foo1Difficult` results -- however when using `na.rm=TRUE` the survey library will only use `complete.cases` and cause a difference in the two statements if any of `foo2` thru `foo20` have missings

Answer (score 0):

As @AnthonyDamico pointed out, the difference was caused by NAs.